# Why aren't torch.nn.Parameter listed when net is printed?

Tags: python, pytorch

I recently had to construct a module that required a tensor to be included. While back propagation worked perfectly using `torch.nn.Parameter`, it did not show up when printing the net object. Why isn't this `parameter` included in contrast to other modules like `layer`? (Shouldn't it behave just like `layer`?)

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class MyNet(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyNet, self).__init__()
        self.layer = nn.Linear(10, 10)
        self.parameter = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(10,10, requires_grad=True))

net = MyNet()
print(net)
```

Output:

```
MyNet(
  (layer): Linear(in_features=10, out_features=10, bias=True)
)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you call `print(net)`, the `__repr__` method is called. [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) gives the “official” string representation of an object.

In PyTorch's [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html) (base class of your `MyNet` model), the `__repr__` is implemented like this:

```
def __repr__(self):
        # We treat the extra repr like the sub-module, one item per line
        extra_lines = []
        extra_repr = self.extra_repr()
        # empty string will be split into list ['']
        if extra_repr:
            extra_lines = extra_repr.split('\n')
        child_lines = []
        for key, module in self._modules.items():
            mod_str = repr(module)
            mod_str = _addindent(mod_str, 2)
            child_lines.append('(' + key + '): ' + mod_str)
        lines = extra_lines + child_lines

        main_str = self._get_name() + '('
        if lines:
            # simple one-liner info, which most builtin Modules will use
            if len(extra_lines) == 1 and not child_lines:
                main_str += extra_lines[0]
            else:
                main_str += '\n  ' + '\n  '.join(lines) + '\n'

        main_str += ')'
        return main_str
```

Note that the above method returns `main_str` which contains call to only `_modules` and `extra_repr`, thus it prints only modules by default.

---

PyTorch also provides [`extra_repr()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.extra_repr) method which you can implement yourself for extra representation of the module.

> To print customized extra information, you should reimplement this method in your own modules. Both single-line and multi-line strings are acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

According to `nn.Parameter` docs:

> Parameters are :class:`~torch.Tensor` subclasses, that have a
>       very special property when used with :class:`Module` s - when they're
>       assigned as Module attributes they are automatically added to the list of
>       its parameters, and will appear e.g. in :meth:`~Module.parameters` iterator.

So you can find it in `net.parameters`. Let's look at the following example:

Code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

torch.manual_seed(42)

class MyNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyNet, self).__init__()
        self.layer = nn.Linear(4, 4)
        self.parameter = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(4, 4, requires_grad=True))
        self.tensor = torch.ones(4, 4)
        self.module = nn.Module()

net = MyNet()
print(net)
```

Output:

```
MyNet(
  (layer): Linear(in_features=4, out_features=4, bias=True)
  (module): Module()
)
```

As you can see, there is no `tensor` or 'parameter' object (because `parameter` is subclass of `tensor`), only `Module`s.

Now let's try to get our net parameters:

Code:

```
for p in net.parameters():
    print(p)
```

Output:

```
Parameter containing:
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([[ 0.3823,  0.4150, -0.1171,  0.4593],
        [-0.1096,  0.1009, -0.2434,  0.2936],
        [ 0.4408, -0.3668,  0.4346,  0.0936],
        [ 0.3694,  0.0677,  0.2411, -0.0706]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([ 0.3854,  0.0739, -0.2334,  0.1274], requires_grad=True)
```

Ok, so the first one is your `net.parameter`. Next two is weights and bias of `net.layer`. Let's verify it:

Code:

```
print(net.layer.weight)
print(net.layer.bias)
```

Output:

```
Parameter containing:
tensor([[ 0.3823,  0.4150, -0.1171,  0.4593],
        [-0.1096,  0.1009, -0.2434,  0.2936],
        [ 0.4408, -0.3668,  0.4346,  0.0936],
        [ 0.3694,  0.0677,  0.2411, -0.0706]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([ 0.3854,  0.0739, -0.2334,  0.1274], requires_grad=True)
```